# React Material-UI Textfield padding top - Thai Language

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, thai

I'm use the library for input. But when use with Thai language, it need additional top padding to display word correctly as Thai has 2 level of vowel. For example, word like "ที่นั่น" will be cut on the top. Below is the code I use.

```
      <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
        <TextField required id="name" label="Remark name" fullWidth />
      </Grid>
```

When i put word "ที่นั่น" inside Textfield will display only this. I try various style to change this but not success.

[Screencap run of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roCPR.png)

Comment: Is not a language problem. Because i'm reproduced you case and everything works. See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-jones-5wt94. I think that you use some style that gives you this problem.

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei Yes, I can set 'label' with Thai language, but the problem happens when I enter something inside Textfield when i run the script.

Comment: see my response and let me know if i'm resolve you problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your comment. For my case, I found out that I need to put paddingTop in InputProps. So, the code I use is:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  thaiTextFieldInputProps:{
    paddingTop: '5px'
  },
});
```

and then

```
<TextField
   InputProps={{
      classes: {
         input: classes.thaiTextFieldInputProps
      }
   }}
   label="Thai Remark"
   fullWidth
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MUI you can use their css wrapper function withStyles like this

```
const styles = theme => ({
  name: {
    paddingTop: '50px', // for example
  },
});
```

and then

```
  <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
    <TextField 
     className={classes.name}
     required 
     id="name"
     label="Remark name"
     fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>
```

After this you just need to wrapp your component in withStyles HOC:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(NameOfYourComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you @Lazar. But it cannot solve the problem. With paddingTop, it just increase the white space between text and label but the content was still blocked by white color.

Comment: Could you maybe create codesandbox like Fiodorov Andrei did in his comment so that we could see what do you mean exactly

Answer (score 0):

To fix you problem need to update default styles:

1. Add class name for text field

```
    <Grid item xs={12} md={10}>
      <TextField
        className="fix-thai" // <<<<<
        required
        id="name"
        label="ที่นั่น"
        fullWidth
      />
    </Grid>
```

2. In you styles add this class and reset styles for `input`:

```
.fix-thai input {
  height: 20px;
}
```

See live example:

[image: Edit vibrant-jones-5wt94]

---

I'm make [pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/20363) to fix it. With new release I think fixed it.